# Using union and then arrange the data with order by from second row onwards

Tags: mysql, syntax, union

lets i have this query

```
select * from items where status = 'A' and staffid = '$var1' and workid != '$var2' order by seq asc
```

and it will result in

1
2
3
4
5

But now i have another query

```
select * from items  where status = 'A' and staffid = '$var1' and workid = '$var2'
UNION
select * from items  where status = 'A' and staffid = '$var1' and workid != '$var2' order by seq asc
```

I would like the second query to return

4
1
2
3
5

The result is that way because the query before the union will return "4" and after that i would love to rearrange the result according to seq ascending. Is there a way to arrange the result of a query based on second or Nth row onwards? Is there such a technique to combine both union and order to get this result? if there isnt , could someone show me another idea. by just using a single query. I know theres and alternative by splitting both query out. I just wanna know in this sense, is it possible. THanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *,1 as tab from items  where status = 'A' and staffid = '$var1' and workid = '$var2'
UNION
select *,2 from items  where status = 'A' and staffid = '$var1' and workid != '$var2' order by tab,seq
```

Comment: okay not sure how yours work but it managed to return almost correct answer. it return 4,5,3,1,2 or smtg like that. the only part it was right is that the number 4 is the first.

Comment: sorri about that. i just manage to see your edit. it works great!! care to explain a little?

Comment: Ok. Please forgive my poor english ;). The trick is to add a field to both queries and give a smallest value to the query that contains result that you want first. So, you can have before results from first query and when the table is the same, you order by the seq field. Hope you have understood despite mi english ;)

Comment: ohh cool stuff..thanks for your explanation. your english not so bad. thanks a bunch again =)